# SSH using Public IP over the VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, vpn

I have an EC2 instance launched in Private Subnet.

I have also launched an AWS Client VPN and did all of the configurations and I am able to connect to my EC2 instance via Private IP.

There is a service running on Port 25, I am able to `telnet` to that as well using the Private IP.

But when I try to do `telnet` using the Public IP of the Instance, I am not able to do so. Also, I am not able to `ssh` into Instance when I am connected to VPN using the Public IP.

How can I `ssh` into my EC2 Instance using Public IP when I am connected to VPN?
I don't want to add my machine's Public IP in the Security Group and then do the SSH.

Comment: public ip in a private subnet..?

Comment: Yes, there is a web service running. So one of my team wanted to access it over a short period of time.

Comment: In private subnet you can't have a public ip! You can't have incoming traffic in a private subnet. You have a NAT and that's it. you can initiate a connection but can't recieve one!https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Comment: Your EC2 instance is in a private subnet. Use EC2 Instance Connect or SSM Session Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an Amazon EC2 instance is in a private subnet (defined as having a Route Table that does *not* point to an Internet Gateway), then **the instance will not be reachable via public IP address**.

Public IP addresses are routed via the Internet Gateway. Since there is no route between the Internet Gateway and the instance, it cannot be reached via the public IP address.